# What do you call a document informing people of an intent?

Tags: word-request

There are documents called will, but this document refers specifically to inheritance, but is there a word for a document that's not necessarily legal like a will, that shows people the intent of the person who wrote it? By intent, I mean it in the most general way possible, such that it can also mean what the person meant when he wrote or uttered a certain phrase.

I don't have any clear real-life example for this, because I don't think there's such a word.

Answer (score 2):

In a formal context, I'd use the term "*Statement of Intent*". To check myself, I did a quick search on that term and came up with examples like, [this](https://worksafe.govt.nz/about-us/corporate-publications/statement-of-intent/) from the New Zealand Government group who are responsible for employees' safety at work. In business, you would usually have a "*[Mission Statement](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mission-statement)*" describing the overall purpose of the business. The above are actual documents.

> By intent, I mean it in the most general way possible, such that it can also mean what the person meant when he wrote or uttered a certain phrase.

Here, I would just call it a *[clarification](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/clarify?q=clarify)*.
You could say, "*I may have been unclear. What I meant was...*", or even less formally, "*Sorry, I meant...*", or "*By that I mean...*", or "*What I mean to say is...*". This clarification could be written or spoken.

(Wikipedia uses the word *disambiguation* for pages that clarify and separate different meanings for the same term: *ambiguous* means, "with more than one meaning", where it is not clear which meaning applies. Example word with two meanings: [Android](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android))